# How to bind multiple object and pass to Angular 9 frontend from Springboot2 backend

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

I have got a List of array for type DailyStat and an object named GoldenRatio at the same time that are required to pass from Springboot2 backend to Angular 9 frontend. How do I set the request body from back-end and how do I read the data in Angular 9?

Sample toString structure:

```
DailyStat [date=20200504, dayOpen=1.09481, dayHigh=1.097785, dayLow=1.097225, dayClose=0.0, dayRange=5.60000000000116E-4, threeDaysAverage=0.0010216666666666649, oneEightDiff=1.277083333333331E-4, oneQuarter=1.0950654166666667, oneEight=1.0949377083333334, negativeOneQuarter=1.0945545833333334, negativeOneEight=1.0946822916666668]
DailyStat [date=20200505, dayOpen=1.091245, dayHigh=1.09261, dayLow=1.091185, dayClose=0.0, dayRange=0.0014250000000000096, threeDaysAverage=0.0010416666666667035, oneEightDiff=1.3020833333333794E-4, oneQuarter=1.091505416666667, oneEight=1.0913752083333335, negativeOneQuarter=1.0909845833333331, negativeOneEight=1.0911147916666666]
DailyStat [date=20200506, dayOpen=1.083305, dayHigh=1.08457, dayLow=1.08435, dayClose=0.0, dayRange=2.20000000000109E-4, threeDaysAverage=0.0013166666666667066, oneEightDiff=1.6458333333333833E-4, oneQuarter=1.0836341666666665, oneEight=1.0834695833333332, negativeOneQuarter=1.0829758333333335, negativeOneEight=1.0831404166666667]
DailyStat [date=20200507, dayOpen=1.07957, dayHigh=1.081645, dayLow=1.080365, dayClose=0.0, dayRange=0.0012799999999999478, threeDaysAverage=7.350000000000781E-4, oneEightDiff=9.187500000000977E-5, oneQuarter=1.07975375, oneEight=1.079661875, negativeOneQuarter=1.0793862499999998, negativeOneEight=1.0794781249999998]
DailyStat [date=20200508, dayOpen=1.08451, dayHigh=1.085495, dayLow=1.084885, dayClose=0.0, dayRange=6.099999999999994E-4, threeDaysAverage=9.750000000000222E-4, oneEightDiff=1.2187500000000277E-4, oneQuarter=1.0847537500000002, oneEight=1.0846318750000001, negativeOneQuarter=1.08426625, negativeOneEight=1.084388125]
GoldenRatio [weekDiff=5.60000000000116E-4, weekHigh=1.097785, weekLow=1.097225, wh0200=1.097673, wh0250=1.097645, wh0333=1.09759852
```

Sample code:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "indicator", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<GoldenRatio> getRatioData(@RequestParam("fromDate") String fromDate, 
                                              @RequestParam("toDate") String toDate, 
                                              @RequestParam("interval") String interval) {

        GoldenRatio gr = new GoldenRatio();
        List<DailyStat> weeklyStat = new ArrayList<DailyStat>();
...

        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(gr);
    }
```

Comment: This [post](https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2019/09/06/angular-http-get-request-examples) can help you, and there are some official [angular documentations](https://angular.io/guide/http) too :)

Answer (score 0):

You can only return a single object from a Spring controller, and you can only receive a single object on the Angular side.

That said, the single object communicated between Spring and Angular can be arbitrarily complex.

The answer in your case is to create another class that contains both of the items that you want to return, and return that instead.

You will need a similar interface or class in Angular to be able to deserialize the result.